# Selecting right import based on string in Go

Tags: go, import, switch-statement

Consider the following

```
import ( "library_a"
         "library_b"
         ...
         "library_z"
```

I want to be able to select the right library based on the letter.

So if I have z as input it will pick library_z.

What is a way to do this without requiring a massive switch statement?

Comment: go does not compile unused libraries, so you can not import libraries at run time, they are eitgher imported and compiled or they are not.

Comment: never mind, i see what you say. so there is no way around a switch statement because you must explicitly reference each of them or they won't be compiled?

Comment: It's not about libraries but the functions/types they are providing. At one point you have to build up a structure that contains all the options you want to choose from at runtime. This could either be a big switch statement or a map containing pointers to whatever you want to use (there are also pointers to functions in Go available).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different libraries then you would have to import all of them and **actually** use them in your code.

From the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

> It is illegal for a package to import itself, directly or indirectly, **or to directly import a package without referring to any of its exported identifiers.**

You will have to use a switch if you want to use different package implementations!